# Sort Order Issue Payflow Pro Checkout Magento ver. 1.9.3.9

Tags: sorting, paypal-payflow-pro

in [Configuration > Payment Methods > PayPal Payment Gateways > Payflow Pro > Basic Settings - PayPal Payflow Pro] there is a "Sort Order" option but it does not work. I am setting this to 0 but the "Payflow Pro" option is showing up as #2, under the "Paypal Credit" option. Please see screenshot.

I've researched this and no one has an answer. I've attempted to reorder in the config.xml but this does not work either unless I am doing it wrong.

[image: Here I am showing you which option I want to be the first option. I don't want it as the second option.]

Thank you in advance for scoping this out.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out.

1) Need to access DB via PHPMyadmin, click the SQL tab, and enter this command:

`select * from core_config_data where path like '%payment%sort_order%';`

The query will display the sort order for all checkout payment method options.

2) Update the paypal_express options to a higher number in the 'value' column. (see screenshot)

The update will move the paypal express and paypal credit options to a lower position on the checkout page. If is not working than you need to set the option you want on the top of the list to a lower number like '0' in the value field. If you don't know which one it is then you can view the source on your checkout page for example

[image]